# Error message appear after running a GRC file

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

can anyone explain the error listed below and how do I go about rectifying it?

```
[FATAL] [UHDSoapyDevice] USB transfer stalled
libusb: warning [libusb_exit] application left some devices open
```

Comment: Do any problems arise from this?

Comment: also, this isn't really nearly enough info to help you – but honestly, since there's probably not much you can do on your own if this is the first error you see, there's not much to answer than the answer I've given. Next time, please give detailled information on what device, what flowgraph, what software, what software versions, what operating system, and what you've tried to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

> libusb: warning [libusb_exit] application left some devices open

You can't rectify this at all. This seems to be a case of a device driver not closing a USB device. That might or might not be a problem.

That's why it says "warning", not "error".

> [FATAL] [UHDSoapyDevice] USB transfer stalled

Some part of the whole software / libusb / Operating system / USB host controller / USB hubs / USB device stack malfunctioned.